# How to increment a key in the dictionary?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to increment a key in the dictionary

```js
var dic = {}
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    dic['key']++        
}
console.log(dic)
```

I don't get the incremented number, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please note that JavaScript doesn't have dictionaries, it has objects.

Comment: Javascript is really complicated for me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to increment `undefined` since there is no `key` property in `dic`, thus you get `NaN`.

Instead, give the `key` property a default value:

```js
var dic = {key: 0}
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    dic['key']++        
}
console.log(dic)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dic = { count1: 0, count2: 10 }

for (var i in dic) {
    if (i === 'count1') {
        dic[i]++;
    }
}
console.log(dic);
```

Are you trying to do anything like this? here you are iterating through the object, if i equals the key you are looking for, it will increment it.